# Getting input string not in a correct format error for Powershell variable in script

Tags: powershell

I've a script that is supposed to read input from a user, and pass that to the script's function. The value is supposed to be of type System.Int64 and even though I have cast it as such, I still get the following error:

> Get-WinEvent : Cannot bind parameter 'MaxEvents'. Cannot convert value "$b" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

I added a line to output the type of the variable using:

```
Write-Host "Type of MaxEntries: " $maxEntries.GetType()
```

And it shows that it is System.Int64 but I still get the same error. Furthermore, if I remove the double-quotes from around the variable in the actual command within the function, I get this error:

> Get-WinEvent : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'MaxEvents'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. 
>   Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

So it gets passed as null in that case. Weirdly though, I write out the value stored inside the MaxEntries variable both outside and inside the function and it properly displays the value I entered.

Below is the script:

```
$DesktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$path = "$DesktopPath\Hashes.txt"
$apiKey = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your VT api key"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your VT account password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
Set-VTAPIKey -APIKey $apiKey -MasterPassword $password

$PatternMD5 = '(?<=MD5=)(.*)(?=,)'
$PatternSHA256 = '(?<=SHA256=)(.*)'


#try{
$days = Read-Host -Prompt "How far back would you like to search the logs (days)?"
#} catch {
#until
#} (($days -ge 1 -and $days -lt 100))
$daysBack = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)


#try{
[int64]$maxEntries = Read-Host -Prompt "What is the maximum number of log events you would like to retrieve? (1-100)?"
#} catch{
#until
#} (($maxEntries -ge 1 -and $MaxEntries -lt 100))
Write-Host "MaxEntries BEFORE function: " $maxEntries

function GetHashes($a, $b){

    Write-Host "daysBack: " $daysBack
    Write-Host "MaxEntries AFTER function: " $maxEntries
    Write-Host "Type of MaxEntries: " $maxEntries.GetType()
    $events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational";StartTime = $a} -MaxEvents $b
    ForEach ($event in $events) {
        if ($event.Message.Contains("Hashes")){
            Write-Host "Event contains hashes"
            # Create hashtable
            $Dictionary = @{}
            # Convert event message to string
            $string = $event.Message.ToString()
            # Split lines in event message based off newline, and remove any null values
            $string.Split([environment]::NewLine,[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) | ForEach-Object {
                #Split each pair into key and value based off ':' delimiter
                $key,$value = $_.Split(':')
                #Write-Host "Key: " $key
                #Write-Host "Value: " $value
                #Populate $Dictionary
                $Dictionary[$key] = $value
                }
           Write-Host "Hashes: " $Dictionary.Item("Hashes")
           $hashes = $Dictionary.Item("Hashes")
           $MD5Hash = ($hashes -match $patternMD5)
           $MD5Hash = $matches[0]

           $SHA256Hash = ($hashes -match $patternSHA256)
           $SHA256Hash = $matches[1]

           $SHA256Hash >> $path
           $MD5Hash >> $path
           #Write-Host "MD5 Hash is: " $MD5Hash
           #Write-Host "SHA256 Hash is: " $SHA256Hash
           Write-Host
           } 
        }
    }
GetHashes $daysBack, $maxEntries
Submit-VTFile $path
```

I want to prompt the user for the maximum number of log entries to be returned `$maxEntries` and then pass that value into `function GetHashes($a, $b)` where it ultimately gets used in this command:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational";StartTime = $a} -MaxEvents $b
```

I have a gut feeling this is something really silly and naive but I would appreciate a nudge or link to some heplful reading material.

I suspect the following:

- casting the maxEntries variable incorrectly
- incorrect use of quotes

Comment: `GetHashes $daysBack, $maxEntries` -> `GetHashes $daysBack $maxEntries`

Comment: OMG. Wow. *facepalm* and many many thanks

Comment: We all need a second pair of eyes once in a while ;-)